Excel VBA codes work fine in the workbook but not when auto-opened from other workbook (userform)
I am no expert of course but 'learning by myself' type (FYI please be simple with me). I have a simple School Record book project.
Sample workbook "IX- students records - sample.xlsm"

Here all the admitted students details are entered in each rows of the table "ADMISSION".
In the next sheet "I_Test" when opened,

there is the excel table (named "I_TEST") where the same number of rows as on the "ADMISSION" table, are added or deleted automatically with the code (in the sheet : "I_Test")
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim ADMISSION As ListObject
    Dim My_table As ListObject
    Dim Last As Long
    
    Set ADMISSION = Sheet1.ListObjects("ADMISSION")
    Set My_table = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("I_TEST")
    Range("C6").Select                                          'to put cursor to Eng mark
    While My_table.Range.Rows.Count < ADMISSION.Range.Rows.Count 
        My_table.ListRows.Add
    Wend
    While My_table.Range.Rows.Count > ADMISSION.Range.Rows.Count
        With My_table.Range
            Last = .Rows.Count
            .Rows(Last).Delete
        End With
    Wend
    

End Sub


This works just fine within the sample workbook itself. But This workbook should be opened from another workbook named "Create new" with Userform, and save a copy with new name (according to data entered on the Userform of the workbook "Create new").
Here is how it goes - Open the workbook "Create New" and the Userform appear (hiding the workbook)

After entering Session and Class, pressing 'Create' key open the sample workbook, save a copy with name "IX-2024-2025" (e.g), closing the userform and the "Create new" workbook, and continue working in the newly saved workbook.
The above code does not work as expected. To my surprise, when closed and reopened the workbook, it works just fine later on.
On opening the worksheet "I_Test", I want the table ("I_TEST") in the sheet to have the same number of rows as in the "ADMISSION" table in the first sheet "ADM", to add or delete automatically as needed.
The above code is behind the worksheet (or worksheet object or whatever, I don't know the technical term) not in the module, Because I want 'each code for each sheet' to execute, to avoid many codes executed at once.
What should I do?? Please....
